# How can I use the Graph API for cross-tenant user delegation？

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

**It's very troubled. Help me.**
I want to use the cross-tenant user delegation Graph API.

**Tenant A:**

- Front App(Angular Node.js Expresss) & Back-end App(Web API C#)
- Authenticate users with Azure AD for this tenant.

**Tenant B:**

- Invite Tenant A users as guests
- This tenant has Share Point.
- Create an AD application to use the Graph API.

The user wants to authenticate with Azure AD using MSAL in Tenant A, obtain an access token for Tenant B with SharePoint, and use the user-delegated Graph API.

A user wants to sign in to an app in Tenant A (authenticated by MSAL) and access SharePoint in Tenant B from the app. I want to use the access rights of the user as it is, so I want to operate on SharePoint with the user-delegated Graph API. I don't want to use Graph API with application permission.
Is it possible to do the above?

I submitted a support request to Microsoft, but did not get a valid answer.

Graph API with cross-tenant application permission has been realized, but user delegation Graph API cannot be realized.

Comment: `Invite Tenant A users as guests` for example I have an account `tiny@tenantA.onmicrosoft.com`, and is invited into tenant me, then I can certainly sign into tenantB with my account, but my account in tenantB should look like `tiny@tenantA.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@tenantB.onmicrosoft.com`. So I'm afraid it's hard for you to use delegate permission. If you insist on using delegate, you can only use ROPC flow which requires to provide the password... and it's not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you TinyWang!!Is it difficult to realize even if the members of Tenant A and the guest users of Tenant B are reversed? Invite a member of Tenant B to Tenant A as a guest, authenticate to the app using MSAL as a guest user, and use Graph API with user delegation to Tenant B.

Comment: basically, when my account from tenentA isinvited to tenantB, then I can certainly sign into tenantB with my account it tenantA, and I can also generate access token to call graph api for tenantB with my tenantA account. But, we need to know, if we use tenantA account generate access token for tenantA, we need to provide tenantA domain/tenantID in the request, when we use tenantA account to generate access token for tenantB, we also need to set the domain/tenantID with tenantB. so in your request, when you integrate AAD for tenantA then using graph sdk, it only works for tenantA.